# Node Twitter bot keeps crashing on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

As a way to try to teach myself a bit of Node and how to use Heroku, I decided to create a simple Twitter bot that should tweet once a day.

When running my bot manually, everything goes fine and it tweets as it should. Once on Heroku, even before I added a scheduler (to run my bot once a day), it started tweeting at random times. I have to keep deleting them. I noticed in the logs, the bot keeps crashing and restarting, which triggers the tweet.

I have Googled for hours and cannot figure out why this is happening. I'm brand new to Node and anything to do with servers in general, so I'm really not sure how to troubleshoot from this point.

I'd appreciate any help in figuring out what is causing my bot to crash.

(I should note, I do have it set up as a `worker` on Heroku, and that is in my `Procfile`. Not sure if this makes a difference.)

**Heroku Logs**:

```
    2018-07-08T16:21:10.427313+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
    2018-07-08T16:21:11.167238+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2018-07-08T16:21:15.159855+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
    2018-07-08T16:21:15.056356+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2018-07-08T16:56:32.097321+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-07-08T16:56:36.064795+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
    2018-07-08T16:56:36.789264+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2018-07-08T16:56:40.212853+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
    2018-07-08T16:56:40.170153+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2018-07-08T17:08:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myemailaddress
    2018-07-08T17:08:23.727988+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 852c8541 by user myemailaddress
    2018-07-08T17:08:23.727988+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user myemailaddress
    2018-07-08T17:08:24.186005+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-07-08T17:08:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2018-07-08T17:08:26.514939+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
    2018-07-08T17:08:27.156637+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2018-07-08T17:08:28.631772+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2018-07-08T17:08:28.723695+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
    2018-07-08T17:08:28.725787+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-07-08T17:08:31.479079+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
    2018-07-08T17:08:32.358515+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2018-07-08T17:08:33.922886+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
    2018-07-08T17:08:33.878013+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2018-07-08T17:12:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myemailaddress
    2018-07-08T17:12:48.895075+00:00 app[api]: Release v18 created by user myemailaddress
    2018-07-08T17:12:48.895075+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1fbb896c by user myemailaddress
    2018-07-08T17:12:49.246800+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-07-08T17:12:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2018-07-08T17:12:53.635812+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
    2018-07-08T17:12:54.327615+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2018-07-08T17:12:57.874384+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
    2018-07-08T17:12:57.852555+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2018-07-08T17:35:48.475654+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2018-07-08T17:35:52.257156+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
    2018-07-08T17:35:52.995975+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2018-07-08T17:35:56.888137+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
    2018-07-08T17:35:56.871199+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

**Bot source code:** 
https://github.com/meowwwls/words-of-tori-amos/blob/master/bot.js

```
    const twit = require('twit');
    const getVideo = require('./youtube');
    const { getLyrics } = require('./lyricadder/lyrics');
    const { randomNumber } = require('./helpers');

    const config = {
      consumer_key: process.env.consumer_key,
      consumer_secret: process.env.consumer_secret,
      access_token: process.env.access_token,
      access_token_secret: process.env.access_token_secret
    };

    const Twitter = new twit(config);

    const lyrics = getLyrics();

    const tweetLyric = () => {
      const random = randomNumber(lyrics.length);
      const lyric = lyrics[random];

      getVideo(lyric.song).then(response => {
        const songHash = lyric.song.replace(/\s/g, '');
        const tweet = {
          status: `${lyric.lyric}\n${response} #ToriAmos #${songHash}`
        };

        Twitter.post('statuses/update', tweet, (err, data, response) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
      });
    };

    tweetLyric();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Heroku support! This was driving me mad. I thought I would share the support answer in case someone else ever comes across this issue. I think the reason Twitter bot tutorials I read didn't have this issue is they all had their bots doing other things as well, such as responding to hashtags, followers, or tweets sent to their bot. Or they were using `setInterval` to tweet, which kept the app running constantly.

I followed this advice and it has been running perfectly.

> The reason for both the crashing is that you are not running a process on your worker dynos, you are just issuing the command to tweet and exiting, heroku web and worker dynos are designed to work off of long running tasks, so your worker is starting, doing a tweet then abruptly exiting and crashing, causing us to detect the crash and spin up a new worker, which just does the same thing round and round in a loop.
>
> If you only want to run the scheduled tweets you can just delete your Procfile and scale down your web and worker dynos, the scheduler will start a separate one-off dyno whenever you have it scheduled too which will run your tweet script for you and exit.